# How to provide the specification of a component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, lit-element

I'm coding a component with TypeScript.

**component**

```
@customElement("my-component")
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {

  @property({type: String}) myProperty = ""

  render() {
     return html`<p>my-component</p>`
  }
}
```

**main**

```html
// <!-- ... -->
<body>
  <my-component * ></my-component>
</body>
```

Is there a way that my IDE provide the `myProperty` attribute when I type  when my cursor is at the star (*) position ?

If yes, is it related to the way to write the component ? Should I add specification elsewhere ?

Or is it only related to my IDE ? I used LitElement with both WebStorm and VSCode and none of them provides the correct custom attribute when typing  (I'm also using lit-plugin on VSCode).

Answer (score 0):

I use [lit-plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=runem.lit-plugin)  and [lit-html](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.lit-html) with VSCode, and that gives me the intellisense you describe in TypeScript files.

I found I [had a lot of pain making sure TS could find the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274072) but once I solved that lit-plugin gave me intellisense and type checking pretty reliably.