# Make TypeScript check a library folder other than node_modules

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I have a process that flattens modules for TypeScript into a folder called `./lib` (instead of `./node_modules`).

I have `skipLibCheck` set and I exclude `./lib` from compilation.

However, when referencing packages in `./lib` they seem to try to resolve from `./node_modules` instead.

Something like:

In `my-file.ts`, which should be compiled by `tsc`:

```
import { thing } from './lib/library/index.js';
```

`tsc` resolved this to `./lib/library/index.d.ts`, which looks something like:

```
export * from '@depTypeLib/typeName';
```

Now this *should* resolve to `./lib/@depTypeLib/typeName.d.ts`, but instead it fails to find it.

> `TS2305` Module './lib/library/index.js' has no exported member 'thing'.

Running `tsc --traceResolution` shows me that it checked `./node_modules/@depTypeLib/typeName.d.ts`, and if I copy the file there it works.

How do I force `tsc` to check the `./lib` path that it does have instead of the `./node_modules` folder that it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this, but it's fairly awful and I don't think it's a good solution.

`tsconfig` lets you specify `paths`, so it looks like this should work:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "node_modules/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

It fails, because `paths` is *only* checked for the initial path, and as soon as `tsc` starts trying to find definitions it ignores paths.

OK, bit of pain, explicitly reference the path should work, right?

```json
    "paths": {
      "@depTypeLib/*": ["lib/@depTypeLib/*"]
    }
```

This fails, it's not remotely clear why, but `tsc --traceResolution` gives an obtuse clue...

```
...
'paths' option is specified, looking for a pattern to match module name '@depTypeLib/typeName'.
'baseUrl' option is set to 'C:/GitHub/project/wwwroot'
...

Directory 'C:/GitHub/project/wwwroot/lib/@depTypeLib/typeName/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
File name 'C:/GitHub/project/wwwroot/lib/@depTypeLib/typeName.js' has a '.js' extension - stripping it.
...repeat for every parent directory
======== Module name '@depTypeLib/typeName' was not resolved. ========
```

It looks like `tsc` has mapped my `baseUrl` to `C:/GitHub/project/wwwroot` (correctly), and then found that a path maps `@depTypeLib/*` to `lib/*` (correctly) and found the correct path `C:/GitHub/project/wwwroot/lib/@depTypeLib/typeName`.

Here `tsc` *should* follow the usual resolution logic and find `typeName.d.ts`, but it doesn't, it just checks for a `node_modules` folder or a `typeName.js` and fails to find definitions in either.

It appears to do this every time there's a `typeName.js` as well as the `typeName.d.ts`.

The solution is to explicitly reference the *definition* file in `paths`:

```json
    "paths": {
      "@depTypeLib/typeName": ["lib/@depTypeLib/typeName.d.ts"]
    }
```

So to fix this:

1. run `tsc --traceResolution`
2. find the `node_modules` death spiral that ends with `======== Module name 'X' was not resolved. ========`
3. find the `.d.ts` for that module manually
4. add the mapping to `paths`
5. go to 1. and repeat until it finishes
6. weep at your now massive `tsconfig` that's doomed every time you add another dependency

There *must* be a better way than this.